# If a worker did not follow instructions, what do we call the document he is asked to compose to explain his actions?

Tags: phrase-request, translation

If a worker did not follow instructions at work, and this has affected the performance of the company, he/she is often asked to write a kind of an explanatory letter to the management. What do we call such letters? A report?

In Russian, it's "объяснительная записка" (explanatory note).

> Georgy Ivanov violated the process logging rules, therefore it's impossible to ascertain the reasons for the bioreactor leak.
>   CAPA plan: Georgy Ivanov must write an **explanatory note** and hand it over to Quality Unit manager Taras Zakharchuk.

Comment: In addition to the document itself, a general process that inquires into how and why something happened can be called a [*post mortem*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/postmortem). Originally used in the sense of medical autopsies, it has expanded into a broader usage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Such a document may very well have different names in different organizations.  I can't think of a single universal English term for this.

The most common term would be

> **Incident Report**

The military may use

> Corrective Action Report

Any organization can up with their own terms

> Self Reporting Response (SRR)
>
> Self Evaluation (SE)
>
> Personal Incident Actions (PIA)
>
> HR52 (literally just Human Resources template #52)

They do this to have some serious sounding acronym.